# AWS RDS - creating a "replica" database daily automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Apologies if this isn't the right place to ask this question.

I'm looking to create an automated copy (backup) of my AWS RDS (MySQL) database daily and have this backup restored daily to another RDS instance and made available to another set of applications

I already have daily backups running and I can create a new rds instance from a backup but I want this to happen automatically within AWS.

Looking through AWS documentation and I can't find anything that fits this purpose but maybe there's a service that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I've done many of these administrative things with a small Lamda script run by a CloudWatch event at a particular time.  Would this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

**AWS Aurora for MySQL and PostgreSQL support AutoScaling.**

Autoscaling dynamically adjusts the number of Replicas available for cluster based on different metrics and policy. When sudden workload increase it'll add move read replicas and when it'll decrease it'll also remove so you don't have to pay for it.

[Aurora AutoScaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Integrating.AutoScaling.html)

AWS RDS doesn't support autoscaling but you can always scale horizontally and vertically manually.

[Scaling Your Amazon RDS Instance Vertically Horizontally](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/scaling-your-amazon-rds-instance-vertically-and-horizontally/)

Comment: Sorry I don't think my question was phrased right, I'm not looking for scaling solutions this is so that I can have an active "copy" of my database that is restored from a backup daily on a seperate instance